# Upper bound of a matrix norm?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let: $D$ be a diagonal $(m\times m)$-matrix with non-negative entries; $A$ be a $(m\times l)$-matrix; $\det(A^tDA)\not=0$. Any suggestion for upper bounds of
$$
\|D^{-1}A(A^tD^{-1}A)^{-1}A^t\|\ ?
$$

Comment: Yes. Sorry! And A^t D^{-1} A is non-singular.

Comment: Which norm is $\|\cdot\|$?